# Binding static member function as callback

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

I'm trying to use `std::bind` to use a member function as a callback to `sigaction` in the `termios.h` header.  I understand special care needs taken with member functions and have read and followed the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610046/stdfunction-and-stdbind-what-are-they-when-they-should-be-used) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055080/how-to-set-a-member-function-as-callback-using-stdbind), with no such luck.

Because I can pass through a static function, I thought if I left the function static, added a second variable as a pointer to itself (`this`), I would be good, but no such luck:

```
// In SerialListener.h
static void callback(int status, SerialListener *ptr);

// In the serial listener constructor

// Set callback
auto cb = std::bind(&SerialListener::callback, std::placeholders::_1, this);
sigAct_.sa_handler = cb;
```

But the error is as follows:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::_Bind<void (*std::_Placeholder<1>, SerialListener*))(int, SerialListener*)>’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}’ in assignment sigAct_.sa_handler = cb;
```

I also tried the variation in the second example w/o static implementation:

```
// In SerialListener.h
void callback(int status);

// In the serial listener constructor

// Set callback
auto cb = std::bind(&SerialListener::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1);
sigAct_.sa_handler = cb;
```

Which produces...

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (SerialListener::*)(int)>(SerialListener*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}’ in assignment sigAct_.sa_handler = cb;
```

Errors look pretty similar, looks like it can't implicitly convert the bind to the handler it needs, but when I look at it from a perspective of input types and return types it should work.  What am I missing?

Comment: @NageG - `static` member of classes/structs are more as normal function: aren't bounded to a specific object and don't know `this`; the `this` treatment regard not-static members.

Comment: Bind returns a sort of closure *object*. It's not convertible to a function pointer. You can't sneak another parameter for `__sighandler_t ` into the call.

Comment: Isn't  `sigaction` from `signal.h`?

Comment: I tried also using `this` and a void pointer in the static function instead, shouldn't `this` implicitly convert to a void pointer and then I can cast it back to the `SerialListener*`? I also tried that and it didn't work, but I don't understand why.

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to get a "user data" pointer into a signal handler, and you need to resort to using a variable that's visible from the handler.

Comment: @VTT, yes you're right.  Sorry, I'm using it with a serial port interrupt and that's why I thought it was `termios.h`

Comment: @NateG: Are you allowed to modify the interface of your callback, perhaps to use a `std::function` instead? It will perform the necessary type-erasure we need for everything to work seamlessly, else you're stuck with the brittle solution like VTT's answer (a static variable that you hope nobody overwrites before you need to use it)

Comment: Yes, I can do whatever i want with my callback.  Ultimately I have a non-member function outside the class who's only argument is the file descriptor for the serial port (which is a member of the class).

Comment: @AndyG, what would the std::function implementation look like?

Comment: @NateG instead of declaring `sa_handler` to be `void (*)(int)`, try declaring it to be `std::function<void(int)>`. Then you should be able to assign a lambda to it like `sa_handler = [this](int signal_code){callback(signal_code, this);}`

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, I thought you were talking about my member function.  No, the sa_handler type i defined in the `signa.h` header, it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither lambda or `bind` can help you to set a function not matching signal handler signature as a signal handler. Note that signal handler function signature does not provide any means to pass a class instance through opaque pointer. The best you can do is to store a pointer to handling context object at some static variable:

```
SerialListener * p_listener;

void On_Signal(int signal_code)
{
    if(p_listener)
    {
         p_listener->DealWith(signal_code); // calling member function
    }
}

p_listener= &my_listener;

sigAct_.sa_handler = &On_Signal;
```

Also note that depending on nature of signal the range of actions allowed in signal handler may be very limited.

Comment: In the example above, if I have multiple instances of `SerialListener`, how can manage the `p_listerner` pointe iff its not passed as an argument to the function?

Comment: @NateG Well, multiple instances of `SerialListener` can not listen to the same signal at the same time. If they are supposed to work from different threads you can use thread local static variable. If they are supposed to deal with different signals then you will need to write separate handlers for each `SerialListener`, each using its own static variable.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  What's tricky is the serial port specific code was outside of the SerialListener class, this approach is the opposite of what I was going for.  I am passing a pointer to a non-member function to the SerialListener class, then it was my hope to inside of that class associate my external callback with that serial port.  It looks like my choices are limited, and I need to revise the architecture a bit.